# Why do these two series result in different answers by ratio test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence, ratio

The series $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2k!}{(k!)^2}$ = 4 diverges by the ratio test.

$\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2k!}{(k!)^2} = (2) \sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{(k!)^2} = (2)\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k!)}$

Is this very bad algebra? When I compute the series $(2)\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$ = 0 converges by the ratio test.

Comment: $(1/(k+1)!)/(1/k!)=\frac 1 {k+1} \to 0$.

Comment: Perhaps you mixed up $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2k!}{(k!)^2}$ and $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}$ ?

Comment: Martin R that was it! Thank you.